# NSURLRequest swift getting fatal error exception

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I am new to swift code.I am getting the following error while i am passing my api to NSMutableRequest.What will be my mistake in this.My code is
my urlString is `http://185.43.139.198/N********e/mer***se?wt=json&c=Chennai&s=ddrrss`

```
 let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
```

and am getting the log console as

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: This usually happens if there are any spaces in the URL. Try percent escaping it (e.g. `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`).

Comment: This is the perfect candidate for a playground

Comment: i hope this could be helpful:
https://timuraykutyildirim.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/replacing-character-in-string-with-swift/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Your `Url` Contain Spaces than it will Return Nil

Try This:

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one :

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
```

Comment: still getting error on "let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)" on this line  for other example url its working

Comment: try Encoding url  `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`